# Is there any way in SASS to nest a tag inside its selector?

Tags: css, sass

Below is a code I have:

```
.page-header {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
```

Now I want to set the font size of the header depending on the tag (h1, h2, h3, etc.). Below is what I currently do it like:

```
h1.page-header {
    font-size: 56px;
}
h2.page-header {
   font-size: 38px;
}
```

Is there any way to nest it something like:

```
.page-header {
    color: #333;

    h1 {
        font-size: 56px;
    }
}
```

(I know this won't work as I expect it, just to give you an idea of what I want).

Comment: That is exactly how you do it.  SASS allows you to nest.

Comment: @Lowkase OP wants to use nesting to produce `h1.page-header` and `h2.page-header`. That's the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`@at-root`**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root) with interpolation [**`#{}`**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) using ampersand [**`&`**](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector) to reference the current selector.

```
.page-header {
  @at-root h1#{&} {
    font-size: 56px;
  }
  @at-root h2#{&} {
    font-size: 38px;
  }
}
```

Will produce:

```
h1.page-header {
  font-size: 56px;
}
h2.page-header {
  font-size: 38px;
}
```

Comment: sick answer! here's a [pen showcasing this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwjmQW). very nice.